# An error with the logic in creating a basic calendar program

Tags: c, calendar

I made a program just for testing purposes, when you hold the key 'p' on the keyboard it spills out every day starting from the 1st of January 2012, it should continue on to 2013 and it does although it goes to 32 January 2013, and this is an error which I have no idea how  to fix, I've been trying to fix this problem for a few hours now and nothing seems to make it work as it should..  (should go to 1st February 2013 after 31st of January)

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int month[] = {0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

int day = 0;
int year = 2012;

char *months[]=
{
    " ",
    " January ",
    " February ",
    " March ",
    " April ",
    " May ",
    " June ",
    " July ",
    " August ",
    " September ",
    " October ",
    " November ",
    " December "
};


int x = 1; //skip the blank element 0, get to January (element 1)

int main()
{

while(1)
{
    char ch;
    ch = getch(); //in_char();

    if(ch == 'p')
    {
        day++;


        if(day == month[x]+1)
        {
            day = 1; //day is equal to the first day of the new month
            month[x]++; //month data increments
            months[x]++; //month display increments
            x++; //element of month array increments to get the data of the next month


            if(year % 4 == 0) //leapyear
            {
                month[2] = 29;
            }
            else
            {
                month[2] = 28;
            }


            if(x == 13) //if 12 months have passed
            {
                year++; //year increments
                day = 1; //initialize day to be day 1 of the next year
                x = 1; //go back to the 'January' element in the array

                if(day == month[x]) //if day is equal to the first month (January) 31 days
                {
                    day = 1;
                    month[x]++; //month data increments
                    months[x]++; //month display increments
                }
            }
        }
        if(year == 9999)
        {
            year = 1;
        }


        printf("%i%s%04i\n",day,months[x],year);
    }
}


return 0;
}
```

output:

```
.
.
.
28 December 2012
29 December 2012
30 December 2012
31 December 2012
1January 2013
2January 2013
3January 2013
4January 2013
5January 2013
6January 2013
7January 2013
8January 2013
9January 2013
10January 2013
11January 2013
12January 2013
13January 2013
14January 2013
15January 2013
16January 2013
17January 2013
18January 2013
19January 2013
20January 2013
21January 2013
22January 2013
23January 2013
24January 2013
25January 2013
26January 2013
27January 2013
28January 2013
29January 2013
30January 2013
31January 2013
**32January 2013**
1February 2013
2February 2013
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
    if(day == month[x]+1)
    {
        day = 1; // reset date...OKAY
        month[x]++; // NOT OKAY
```

by doing `month[x]++` you are incrementing the number of days allowed in the month. Instead you need to keep a variable to track the month,just as you've done with day and year..

Comment: And also remove "months[x]++; //month display increments". No need to increment the month name

Comment: Ah yes I see, Thanks a lot for pointing this out to me, it works now. Appreciate your help!